# How to split one cell in data with a limiter into 2 cell in R Studio AND SQL

Tags: sql, r

How to split one cell in data with a limiter into 2 cell in R Studio AND SQL

For example:

```
      col1    col2              
row1: abc      a+b
row2: xyz      d+g+h+i+l
```

so on

**TO**

```
      col1    col2              
row1: abc      a
row2: abc      b
row3: xyz      d
row4: xyz      g
row5: xyz      h
row6: xyz      i
row6: xyz      l
```

so on 
Thanks!! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R you can use `cSplit`. It's perfect for this.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "col2", sep = "+", direction = "long")
#    col1 col2
# 1:  abc    a
# 2:  abc    b
# 3:  xyz    d
# 4:  xyz    g
# 5:  xyz    h
# 6:  xyz    i
# 7:  xyz    l
```

where `df` is

```
structure(list(col1 = c("abc", "xyz"), col2 = c("a+b", "d+g+h+i+l"
)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("row1:", 
"row2:"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works... It would be great if someone helps in SQL query using cursors as well. That would help dealing with databases in SQL server..